# Generating random/sample json based on a schema in Scala

Tags: scala, circe, scalacheck

I need to generate some radom json sample, compliant to a schema dynamically. Meaning that the input would be a schema (e.g. json-schema) and the output would a json that complies  to it.

I'm looking for pointers. Any suggestions ?

Comment: By json-shcema, do you mean this - https://json-schema.org/specification.html ?

Comment: It does not have to be. The important bit is that I have somehow a representation of the schema, and then interpret it to generate a sample

Comment: Major part of your problem is to define that schema, write schema parser with schema AST. Then you need to somehow traverse your schema AST and generate random values for each node (those random value generators should be schema aware). This problem looks more than 90% unrelated to circe or any other json library. Or you can hook into json-schema AST from some json-schema lirary and build on top of that.

Comment: Thank you. In fact, i just realized that my description was not super accurate. The json i need to generate has some predefined structure.  It is an object that can contain an arbitrary  number of key:value (where value is String or Doube) and/or Key:Array where the content of Array  is  "String or Double". So the schema would tell me the  number of key:value and/or key/array

Comment: That should simplify the problem

Comment: Found something promising https://github.com/imrafaelmerino/json-scala-values#-defining-random-json-generators

Answer (score 0):

This is not complete solution, but you can get it from here.

Let's assume we have our domain objects we want to generate:

```
case class Dummy1(foo: String)
case class Dummy11(foo: Dummy1)
```

If we do this:

```
object O {
  implicit def stringR: Random[String] = new Random[String] {
    override def generate(): String = "s"
  }

  implicit def intR: Random[Int] = new Random[Int] {
    override def generate(): Int = 1
  }

  implicit def tupleR[T1: Random, T2: Random]: Random[(T1, T2)] = new Random[(T1, T2)] {
    override def generate(): (T1, T2) = {
      val t1: T1 = G.random[T1]()
      val t2: T2 = G.random[T2]()
      (t1, t2)
    }
  }
}

object G {
  def random[R: Random](): R = {
    implicitly[Random[R]].generate()
  }
}
```

then we will be able to generate some primitive values:

```
  import O._

  val s: String = G.random[String]()
  val i: Int = G.random[Int]()
  val t: (Int, String) = G.random[(Int, String)]()

  println("s=" + s)
  println("i=" + i)
  println("t=" + t)
```

Now to jump to custom type we need to add

```
  def randomX[R: Random, T](f: R=>T): Random[T] = {
    val value: Random[R] = implicitly[Random[R]]
    new Random[T] {
      override def generate(): T = f.apply(value.generate())
    }
  }
```

to our `G` object.

Now we can

```
  import O._
  val d1: Dummy1 = G.randomX(Dummy1.apply).generate()
  println("d1=" + d1)
```

and with some extra effort even

```
  import O._
  implicit val d1Gen: Random[Dummy1] = G.randomX(Dummy1.apply)
  val d11: Dummy11 = G.randomX(Dummy11.apply).generate()
  println("d11=" + d11)
```

Now you need to extend it to all primitive you have, add real implementation of random and support classes with more then 1 field and you ready to go.

You may even make some fancy library out of it.